# Create AWS S3 bucket upload policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to be able to let AWS upload billing CSV to S3. This requires an IAM policy. I have one IAM user that I gave AmazonS3FullAccess. In the bucket properties I can add a policy. Then a policy editor pops up, with a link to a [policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). There I see a form with the following values:

- Policy type: S3 bucket policy
- Effect: allow
- Principal: ???
- AWS Service: S3 (cannot be changed)
- Action: PutObject
- ARN: arn:aws:s3:::xyzbillingreport/keyname???

**Questions**

1. What is the principal and what do I put there?
2. What is the keyname? Where do I find it?
3. Is the PutObject action enough to upload a billing report, or do I need more?

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions

**What is the principal and what do I put there?**

*---The principal is the ARN of the IAM user, role or account that you want to grant or deny access in this policy.*

**What is the keyname? Where do I find it?**

*---What S3 calls "Keys" you may call a "folder", it is the sub folders you create within the bucket. If do not wish to add that level of specificity to your permissions you can just supply the bucket*

**Is the PutObject action enough to upload a billing report, or do I need more?**

*---This really depends on what/who is uploading the file and how. If you are using the CLI to directly upload to the target bucket then "s3:Put*" is fine, if a person is using the console or uploading software, they will also need "s3:List*"*